# Controller card(s) for handling eight USB 2.0 devices at full speed

Tags: usb

Connecting two USB2 devices to an external USB2/3 HUB, connected to one USB2/3 port would normally limit the average read-speed to 240 Mb/s, and continuing adding devices would limit the average speed to 480Mb/s divided by number of devices.

The same would be if I use a USB controller card on the mainboard of most computers, as they are normally implemented using only one [USB channels](https://superuser.com/a/405356/506409).

I guess the solution for handling eight devices in full speed is to get USB controller(s) that is implemented using eight dedicated channels to handle the speed of all of the devices.

It does exist an USB controller card that are able to handle full speed of four USB 3.0 devices ([PEXUSB3S44V](https://www.dustinhome.no/product/5010815847)). Four two of these the total would cost about $255 here in Norway. As I do not need the speed of USB 2.0 this price is a bit to much.

Are there any other alternatives that would handle 8 or 2*4 USB 2.0 drives at full speed to a cheaper price than $255?

Comment: I can't find any with 8 ports that are still being sold. Would one with 7 ports work? Or would 2x4 work?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, make sure it's actual distinct controllers, and not a single-controller-with-internal-hub card.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Both 1x7 and 2x4 should work as long as they have individual channels for each USB2 port. I could use one channel from the mainboard USB controller for the eight device.

Comment: check this out: http://www.amazon.com/OctoFire-Powered-Windows-Charges-Android/dp/B016BZESKK/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1456807065&sr=1-1&keywords=skiva+octofire   Unfortunately, I don't know if it is available or cost in your country.

Comment: I suggest using two or more controller devices to get to your 8 device maximum; this should allow you to save money. For example, you could get one of these: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815166038&cm_re=usb_addon_card--15-166-038--Product

Much cheaper probably even in Finland due to the lower PCI-E width. Then add one of these: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812117104&cm_re=usb_header_cables--12-117-104--Product, which will allow you to add ports if you have an onboard 3.0 header that's going unused.

Answer (score -1):

OK, finally have a [solution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011I5ZP9G)

What you do is install this to get 5 ports, then add a [cable to out panel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013QSTWIS) adapter  to get a full **9** off a single controller.

Speeds may be limited by the controller or the PCI-E 2.0 1x bus, but then again, USB drives usually perform far below theoretical maximums, so you might experience no bottlenecks at all.

Then again, it might also be really expensive in Norway...